# Bash: Usage of -d is giving wrong result

Tags: bash, shell, awk, sed, grep

I have written following `if-else statement` to check if `directorya*` or `directoryb*` exists or not

```
if [ -d /opt/directorya* ] || [ -d /opt/directoryb* ]; then
 echo "SUCCESS"
else
 echo "FAil
fi
```

However, I am getting `FAIL` even when one of the directory exists

All servers are using `bash`

Please note the `asterik` in the directory names `directorya*` `directoryb*`

Here, `directorya*` means all directories which start with `directorya` name.

Here, `directoryb*` means all directories which start with `directoryb` name.

Comment: My question has `asterik` in the directory name `directorya*`

Comment: Yes, this is correct, it should be success if AT LEAST ONE directory starting with either `directorya...` or `directoryb...` exists

Answer (score 3):

Dump the directories into an array and count them:

```
shopt -s nullglob
dirs=(/opt/directory[ab]*/)

if ((${#dirs[@]})); then
    echo "success"
else
    echo "fail"
fi
```